# take data from 3 table where 2nd and 3rd table's name will be dynamic and create from 1st table's columns

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, psql

I need to get data from dynamic joining table . you can be use cursor or join or any thing.
I need pl/pgSQL function to take data from 3 table .
my primary table is static but my second 2 tables are dynamic .

my second and third table make by following my 1st tables x column and y column .
my 2nd column make by 'table'||tableA.x value
my 3rd column make by 'table'||tableA.y value

for every rows data my 2nd and 3rd column will be change .
2nd and 3rd table can be from 50+ table. so, I don't bind table name as static .

I provided an image as demo of my expectation.

[image]

[image]